# Responsive SVG not showing full version at larger screen sizes

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following SVG

```
<svg width="535" height="242" viewBox="0 0 535 242" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>SVG</title>
  <style>
    #text {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
      #text {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <g>
    <path id="logo" fill="#FFF" d=""/>
    <path id="text" fill="#FFF" d=""/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

which should only show a logo mark on small screens and the logo mark with text next to it on larger screens.

If I view the SVG directly in a browser in a large window I can see both logo mark and text, and if I make the window smaller, the text disappears.

But if I add the SVG to an `img` tag, e.g. `<img src="logo.svg">` and view it in a browser, I only get the logo mark, no matter what size the window is.

I've been comparing what I'm doing to this https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveSVGs/img/logo_mq.svg which works whether I view the SVG directly or linked in an `img` tag and I can't see how mine is set up any differently from theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add styles to SVG's like this:

```
<svg width="700" height="242" viewBox="0 0 535 242" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title>SVG</title>
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
            #text {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            @media all and (min-width: 768px) {
                #text {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
        ]]></style>
    </defs>
  <g>
    <path id="logo" fill="#f00" d=" ... "/>
    <path id="text" fill="#000" d=" ... "/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When the style is embedded within the SVG file, the `@media` query takes the width of the SVG element, not the window's width. This makes the SVG attribute `width=535` always render the id `text`. If you want the SVG to react to the entire width of the page, use inline SVG's. Additionally, this can be done by not defining the width or height of the SVG, which allows the HTML page to define the size of the SVG, making the SVG change its state.

Comment: The link I posted in my original post comes from https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveSVGs/index6.html where you can see that the SVG is added in an `img` tag and yet it still changes depending on the overall screen width. What you're saying makes sense, but I don't understand how the Codrops example works, yet mine, which is set up pretty much the same way, doesn't.

Comment: The example changed depending on the width of the SVG element. Check the dev tools and watch the width. It will break at 250 and 200px, which is what was defined in the embedded CSS.